# Template hierarchy like Wordpress

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal. Is there any template hierarchy structure to output different section of durpla like node, page, vocabulary, block etc. If so how can we use that.

E.g. In WordPress we have a template hierarchy to output page, posts, category, custom post etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Drupal has a modular, hierarchical template system. Each of the components you mentioned can be themed individually. The main html template includes the page template, which includes other templates, that include other templates, and on it goes.

See [About overriding themable output](https://www.drupal.org/node/173880) for the how/what/why.

Comment: So it's means that we can change the UI for a node or a block as per our requirement like we do in WordPress such as changing a UI design for a custom post by using single-{custom-post-type}.php file.

Comment: Similar, but not identical. Read through the documentation, it'll give you the specifics